# Session state timeout value to keep for both windows and forms based single .Net application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

We have .Net MVC web application which is integrated using ADFS having both Windows and forms based authentication in a single hosted application.
We are saving some extra user data in the session object after the user is authenticated. Now want to know how much we can keep the sessionstate as to avoid session object expire but user is still authenticated. 
Please note, user context object has only few user data, but we are storing some extra information in the session object, Like Session["UserData"] = extraData;
please advice.

Comment: what do you mean  by 'how much we can keep the sessionstate'.

Comment: As sessionstate will be in minutes, so how much ideal time to handle these scenarios as SSO is also enabled in my application. if session expires then how can i reload the data. still the user is authenticated. These are the details i am looking into.

Comment: in IIS you have default session time out as 20 minutes.you feel like changing it you can change that.once user session expires you can ask user to log in again.session is one per user and we use session to store user specific data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shreesha. But as i mentioned, it is SSO based application where user will not get login screen. he is authenticated using ADFS. So user will always be authenticated. But how about sessionstate timings expiration handled effectively and what would be the ideal session state we can keep.